# idl: pass keyword dynamically to isa function to test structure read by read_csv

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am using IDL 8.4.  I want to use isa() function to determine input type read by read_csv().  I want to use /number, /integer, /float and /string as some field I want to make sure float, other to be integer and other I don't care.  I can do like this, but it is not very readable to human eye.

```
str = read_csv(filename, header=inheader)
; TODO check header
if not isa(str.(0), /integer) then stop
if not isa(str.(1), /number) then stop
if not isa(str.(2), /float) then stop
```

I am hoping I can do something like

```
expected_header = ['id',       'x',       'val']
expected_type   = ['/integer', '/number', '/float']
str = read_csv(filename, header=inheader)
if not array_equal(strlowcase(inheader), expected_header) then stop
for i=0l,n_elements(expected_type) do
  if not isa(str.(i), expected_type[i]) then stop
endfor
```

the above doesn't work, as '/integer' is taken literally and I guess isa() is looking for named structure.   How can you do something similar?

Ideally I want to pick expected type based on header read from file, so that script still works as long as header specifies expected field.

EDIT:

my tentative solution is to write a wrapper for ISA().  Not very pretty, but does what I wanted... if there is cleaner solution , please let me know.

Also, read_csv is defined to return only one of long, long64, double and string, so I could write function to test with this limitation.  but I just wanted to make it to work in general so that I can reuse them for other similar cases.

```
function isa_generic,var,typ
; calls isa() http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ISA.html with keyword
; if 'n', test /number
; if 'i', test /integer
; if 'f', test /float
; if 's', test /string
  if typ eq 'n' then return, isa(var, /number)
  if typ eq 'i' then  then return, isa(var, /integer)
  if typ eq 'f' then  then return, isa(var, /float)
  if typ eq 's' then  then return, isa(var, /string)
  print, 'unexpected typename: ', typ
  stop
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDL has some limited reflection abilities, which will do exactly what you want:

```
expected_types =  ['integer', 'number', 'float']
expected_header = ['id',      'x',      'val']
str = read_csv(filename, header=inheader)
if ~array_equal(strlowcase(inheader), expected_header) then stop
foreach type, expected_types, index do begin
    if ~isa(str.(index), _extra=create_struct(type, 1)) then stop
endforeach
```

It's debatable if this is really "easier to read" in your case, since there are only three cases to test. If there were 500 cases, it would be a lot cleaner than writing 500 slightly different lines.

This snipped used some rather esoteric IDL features, so let me explain what's happening a bit:

`expected_types` is just a list of (string) keyword names in the order they should be used.

The `foreach` part iterates over `expected_types`, putting the keyword string into the `type` variable and the iteration count into `index`.

This is equivalent to using `for index = 0, n_elements(expected_types) - 1 do` and then using `expected_types[index]` instead of `type`, but the `foreach` loop is easier to read IMHO. Reference [here](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/FOREACH.html).

`_extra` is a special keyword that can pass a structure as if it were a set of keywords. Each of the structure's tags is interpreted as a keyword. Reference [here](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Keyword_Inheritance.html).

The `create_struct` function takes one or more pairs of (string) tag names and (any type) values, then returns a structure with those tag names and values. Reference [here](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/CREATE_STRUCT.html).

Finally, I replaced `not` ([bitwise not](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Bitwise_Operators.html)) with `~` ([logical not](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Logical_Operators.html)). This step, like `foreach` vs `for`, is not necessary in this instance, but can avoid headache when debugging some types of code, where the distinction matters.

--

Reflective abilities like these can do an awful lot, and come in super handy. They're work-horses in other languages, but IDL programmers don't seem to use them as much. Here's a quick list of common reflective features I use in IDL, with links to the documentation for each:

- [`create_struct`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/CREATE_STRUCT.html) - Create a structure from (string) tag names and values.
- [`n_tags`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/N_TAGS.html) - Get the number of tags in a structure.
- [`_extra`, `_strict_extra`, and `_ref_extra`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Keyword_Inheritance.html) - Pass keywords by structure or reference.
- [`call_function`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/call_function.html) - Call a function by its (string) name.
- [`call_procedure`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/call_procedure.html) - Call a procedure by its (string) name.
- [`call_method`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/call_method.html) - Call a method (of an object) by its (string) name.
- [`execute`](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/execute.html) - Run complete IDL commands stored in a string.

Note: Be **very careful** using the `execute` function. It will blindly execute any IDL statement you (or a user, file, web form, etc.) feed it. Never ever feed untrusted or web user input to the IDL `execute` function.

Comment: Thank you for reply! This _extra seems to be the things I was looking for.  What's the significance of value 1 in create_structure?  I tried with other values, strings etc, but seems to be ignored?  is it just a place holder to create a structure with right tag?

Comment: @yosukesabai The value 1 is passed as the value of the keyword. IDL passes a 16-bit integer value of 1 (`1S`) for a keyword's value when you pass the keyword with a forward slash like `/number` or `/float`. In other words, the IDL statement `result = isa(value, /integer)` is just a shortcut for writing `result = isa(value, integer=1S)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the keywords quite like that, but there is a `typename` parameter to `ISA` that might be useful. This is untested, but should work:

```
expected_header = ['id', 'x', 'val']
expected_type = ['int', 'long', 'float']
str = read_cv(filename, header=inheader)
if not array_equal(strlowcase(inheader), expected_header) then stop
for i = 0L, n_elemented(expected_type) - 1L do begin
  if not isa(str.(i), expected_type[i]) then stop
endfor
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.  Yeah, I knew typename can be used, but to use that I have to specify specific variety of type, e.g, has to be 'long', instead of /numeric:  test with isa(x, 'long') returns true only if x is 32-bit signed, whereas I want to accept x if it is any numeric type...